# Displaying date from monday to sunday

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I want to make a table weekly schedule , and I need to attach the dates in html markup. So far I got this code :

```
    <table class="schedule-table">
        <tr class="days-tr">
         <td> 
            <span><?php echo $date = date("dS",strtotime('monday this week')).' -  '.date("dS",strtotime("sunday this week")); ?> </span>
            <span> <?php echo $date = date("M-Y",strtotime('monday this week')); ?></span>
        </td>
        <td data-workout-day="<?php echo $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime('monday this week')); ?>">Monday</td>
        <td data-workout-day="<?php echo $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime('tuesday this week')); ?>">Tuesday</td>
        <td data-workout-day="<?php echo $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime('wednesday this week')); ?>">Wednesday</td>
        <td data-workout-day="<?php echo $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime('thursday this week')); ?>">Thursday</td>
        <td data-workout-day="<?php echo $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime('friday this week')); ?>">Friday</td>
        <td data-workout-day="<?php echo $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime('saturday this week')); ?>">Saturday</td>
        <td data-workout-day="<?php echo $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime('sunday this week')); ?>">Sunday</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And here is the output :

```
<table class="schedule-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="days-tr">
            <td> 
                <span>16th -  15th </span>
                <span> Mar-2015</span>
            </td>
            <td data-workout-day="16-Mar-2015">Monday</td>
            <td data-workout-day="10-Mar-2015">Tuesday</td>
            <td data-workout-day="11-Mar-2015">Wednesday</td>
            <td data-workout-day="12-Mar-2015">Thursday</td>
            <td data-workout-day="13-Mar-2015">Friday</td>
            <td data-workout-day="14-Mar-2015">Saturday</td>
            <td data-workout-day="15-Mar-2015">Sunday</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see it takes the Monday date from following week instead of 9-Mar-2015 ? How to fix that to display it properly? (for example if we have Friday 13-Mar i want the mon, tues, thur to have dates from previous week not the following.

Answer (score 1):

If you are assuming that you week is starting from monday

then first of all check

```
$day = date('l')
if($day != 'Monday'){
echo $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime( "previous monday" ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` is hugely powerful and can accept a lot of strings to get the desired date. In this case, you want `this week` to get this weeks dates.

By changing 'next monday' etc to 'this week monday' you get the dates for Monday of this current week:

```
<table class="schedule-table">
    <tr class="days-tr">
    <td> 
        <span><?php echo $date = date("dS",strtotime('this week')).' -  '.date("dS",strtotime("this week sunday")); ?> </span>
        <span> <?php echo $date = date("M-Y",strtotime('monday this week')); ?></span>
    </td>
    <td data-workout-day="<?php echo $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime('this week monday')); ?>">Monday</td>
    <td data-workout-day="<?php echo $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime('this week tuesday')); ?>">Tuesday</td>
    <td data-workout-day="<?php echo $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime('this week wednesday')); ?>">Wednesday</td>
    <td data-workout-day="<?php echo $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime('this week thursday')); ?>">Thursday</td>
    <td data-workout-day="<?php echo $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime('this week friday')); ?>">Friday</td>
    <td data-workout-day="<?php echo $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime('this week saturday')); ?>">Saturday</td>
    <td data-workout-day="<?php echo $date = date("d-M-Y",strtotime('this week sunday')); ?>">Sunday</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Generates:

```
<table class="schedule-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="days-tr">
            <td> 
                <span>09th -  15th </span>
                <span> Mar-2015</span>
            </td>
            <td data-workout-day="09-Mar-2015">Monday</td>
            <td data-workout-day="10-Mar-2015">Tuesday</td>
            <td data-workout-day="11-Mar-2015">Wednesday</td>
            <td data-workout-day="12-Mar-2015">Thursday</td>
            <td data-workout-day="13-Mar-2015">Friday</td>
            <td data-workout-day="14-Mar-2015">Saturday</td>
            <td data-workout-day="15-Mar-2015">Sunday</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```